# php How to upload to shortcut directory "symbolic link directory"

Tags: php, laravel, upload, symlink

I want to upload files to shortcut directory "symbolic link directory",
php makes new directory instead of uploading to symolic link folder

here is my code " laravel"

```
$allowed = array("image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/pjpeg", "image/gif", "image/x-png", "image/png");
$file=$request->file('logo');
$extension = $file->getClientMimeType();
if (in_array($extension, $allowed)) {
    $new_name = md5($file->getClientOriginalName()) . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file_name   = "/uploads/images/channels/" . $new_name;
    if($file->move("uploads/images/channels",$new_name)){
        $path = $file_name;
    }
}
$channel->logo = $path;
```

Comment: I'm using xampp for windows for devlopment

Comment: where is your actual directory? where you want to save... full path please.

Comment: for testing on local machine , I made the folder on C:\uploads\channels and shortcut on public directory inside my app

Comment: You can't store the file into shortcut on windows. It has to be the real path of the folder!

Comment: @lewis4u does upload to symbolic link folder will work under Linux

Comment: yes...the shortcut on windows is not the same thing as symbolic link on linux!

Comment: How are you creating `"symbolic link directory"`?